# Restore a git directory after remove it

Tags: git, remote-server

I had a git repo in a remote server and a cloned directory in my local PC. By mistake, I deleted the .git folder in the remote server, but that folder is still in my local PC.

Is there a way of restore the files to my remote server?

Comment: There are any number of ways to move files between servers. Do you have a more specific question? If so, please provide more specific information.

Comment: Hi @isherwood . I can move the folder with scp command, yes. But I don't know if some files of git can differ between origin directory and clone directory, so maybe a direct copy isn't a good idea.

Comment: There likely were differences, but short of running some undelete software on your server that's your best option. Is that what you're asking... how to restore deleted files in general? That's not a Git question.

Answer (score 0):

Restoring the .git folder in the remote server with what is available locally should do it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to restore your local cloned repository on the remote server:

- make a bundle from your local repo
- scp that one bundle file to the server
- clone from the bundle on the remote server

That is:

```sh
cd /path/to/local/repo
git bundle create ../mybundle --all
scp ../mybundle user@remoteServer:mybundle
```

On the remote server

```sh
cd /path/to/old/repo
mv repo oldrepo
git clone ~/mybundle repo
```